# Fortran integer precision mixing

Tags: integer, fortran, precision

Recently, I had to increase the precision for some integer variables in my code. Now I have a mixing of integer kinds and I wonder about the basic stuff about them. For example, suppose I have this variables:

```
integer, parameter    :: idp = selected_int_kind(18) 
integer, parameter    :: isp = selected_int_kind(8) 

integer(isp)       :: a,i
integer(idp)       :: da,di
```

The asignment `a=da` is ok? and what about `da=1_isp`? or `da=da+1`?
In the case of a loop `do di=1,da` is allowed? or I have to do `do di=1_idp,da`?

In the case:

```
subroutine stackof(b,c)
    integer(isp)       :: b,c
    .....
```

can I call `stackof(1_isp,da)`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The asignment a=da is ok?

Yes, if da is in the isp range, you might get warnings though.

> and what about da=1_isp?

Yes, see above.

> or da=da+1?

Same.

In most cases, I think it's worth to use explicit casting like da = int(a, kind=idp).
That will also avoid warnings by the compiler.

> In the case of a loop do di=1,da is allowed?

Tricky, I guess it might work, if the compiler supports long integers as loop counters. But, I would be cautious with that.

> can I call stackof(1_isp,da)

No, type, kind and rank have to match.

Comment: Thanks!. So, the use of long integers in a loop could be dangerous... this is a problem since my precision changes were initially start with a "short" loop. So, I supouse that the best choice to enlarge this loop is to add another one?

Comment: I am not really sure, if it is a problem. I dimly remember to have had issues long time ago. However, for array indicies it definitely might be an issue, especially on 32bit machines, so my attitude is to rather avoid long integers for loop counts as well as array indices. Yet, if portability is not your foremost concern it might be fine enough to use long integers here. Still, I wouldn't mix integer kinds in this case. Best thing to do is to try this with various compilers, I think.